# Unable to send emails in Spring Boot using Gmail SMTP

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to send emails in Spring Boot using `JavaMailSender`. Whenever I run my project I get this error:

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
>   530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 ps2sm10628859pab.10 - gsmtp

I'm not using 2-step verification for my account and the password is right too, I checked it.

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
sprint.mail.username = apptestacc1234@gmail.com
sprint.mail.password = *******
send.from.email= apptestacc1234@gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true;
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.socketFactory.fallback=false
spring.mail.smtp.port= 587
```

My MailService class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MailService {

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;


//public MailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
//  this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
//}


public void sendMail() throws MailException{

    SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
    mail.setTo("loonaishmita@gmail.com");
    mail.setFrom("apptestacc1234@gmail.com");
    mail.setSubject("Test");
    mail.setText("test mail");
    javaMailSender.send(mail);
}
```

}

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MailController {
    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

@RequestMapping("/api/sendmail")
@ResponseBody
private String sendMail() {
    try{
        mailService.sendMail();
        return "mail sent";
    }catch(MailException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "thanks";
}
```

}

I followed almost all the threads related to this problem on stackoverflow but still not able to figure it out. Please help!

Comment: did you configure the gmail account to accept IMAP / POP3 requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any chance that might be a typo in your configuration?

Look at

```
 sprint.mail.username
```

Shouldn't it be `spring...`?

Answer (score 5):

Turn on **Less secure apps**

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

FYI: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Then re-test sending email.

Comment: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps this is actual problem, There are lots of code available but Google is rejecting to login.